# How to ssh-copy-id through a jump-host? Something similar to the -J option with ssh command

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys

I use a jump host to connect to the remote servers through SSH.

I use the following linear command for the connection.

`ssh -J jumpuser@jumphost:2455 remoteuser@remotehost`

It works fine.

But for new servers I need to setup passwordless SSH, So I tried with the following command:

`ssh-copy-id -J jumpuser@jumphost:2455 remoteuser@new-remotehost`

But it throws the error:

`/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: invalid option (-J)`

It is clear that I can't use -J with the **ssh-copy-id** command, But I want to find out if there is an alternate way.

I know how to add the key to the remote server manually, but I want to save time and effort (Lazy ).

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried defining the jump connection in ~/.ssh/config and then attempting the ssh-copy-id?

I seem to recall doing something like that a few years ago to work around not being able to use the needed flags.

Alternatively judicious use of the `-o` flag might be helpful?

[Edit/Update]

**`-o`** worked as follows:

```
ssh-copy-id -o ProxyJump=jumpuser@jumphost:2455 remoteuser@remotehost
```

Comment: Thank you @Stygge, option '-o' worked, I added the command to your answer. You can approve it.

Comment: You're welcome - I'm glad it helped ;)